# Deliver iPhone apps over the air using SSL client certificate authentication

Tags: ios, iphone, ssl, ota

I have an https server with a certificate verified by GeoTrust which uses a self-signed client certificate authentication.

I have imported the certificate chain on my iPhone and the self signed certificate.

Using Safari I can log in to the https site, even download the plist file, but when I click on the `itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=xyz.host.de/ota/app.plist` link I get this error:

```
Could not load download manifest with underlying error: 
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1206 "Cannot connect to xyz.host.de" 
# kCFURLErrorClientCertificateRequired       = -1206,
UserInfo=0x17052dc0 
{
NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://xyz.host.de/ota/app.plist, 
_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9829, 
NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://xyz.host.de/ota/app.plist, 
_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, 
NSUnderlyingError=0x15ff5d80 "The server “xyz.host.de” requires a client certificate.", 
NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=<SecTrustRef: 0x17286270>, 
NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to xyz.host.de
}
```

My guess is that the App Store app is not able to handle client certificate authentication. Any way to solve this? I tested this on iOS 7, 8 and 9 always getting the same result.

Comment: Any resolution to this.  We are seeing the same thing with our OTA installs.